# Can't listen for signUp and EmailRegistration events on Supabase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, supabase

I'm trying to catch a user register and email confirmation event.
In the register page, I have supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange event listener that redirects them to another screen saying to click on the link on the email when the user signUp.

In this confirmation screen, I have another event listener that tracks the confirmation process. When I happens, it redirects them to the main page.

The docs says:

> If Confirm email is enabled, a user is returned but session is null.
>
> If Confirm email is disabled, both a user and a session are returned.

So, here's the event listener on the register page:

```
late final StreamSubscription<AuthState> _authSubscription;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _authSubscription = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((event) {
      final session = event.session;
      print('printing session on RegisterPage: $session\n\n');
      if (session?.user != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/confirm_email');
      }
    });
  }
```

The listener on the confirmation email page:

```
late final StreamSubscription<AuthState> _authSubscription;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _authSubscription = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((event) {
      final session = event.session;
      print('printing session on ConfirmEmailPage: $session\n\n');
      if (session?.user != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
      }
    });
  }
```

My email confirmation is on.
I didn't see any print on the degub console either.
Can you guys help me stop the issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If Confirm email is enabled, a user is returned but session is null.
>
> If Confirm email is disabled, both a user and a session are returned.

The above is talking about the return value of `.signUp()` call, and not the behavior of the `onAuthStateChange` event callback.

For the register page, if you just want to show a confirmation page to the user after the signUp, no need to do anything with the `onAuthStateChange` callback, and just navigate the user after the `.signUp()` call like this:

```dart
await supabase.auth.signUp(
  // the user credentials here
);

Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/confirm_email');
```

You are correct at relying on the `onAuthStateChange` on the confirmation page, so keep that one.